# Start a new process and Killing the current process

Tags: c#, process

I want to start a new process B.exe from the current executing process A.exe.

And as soon as B.exe is launched I want to kill A.exe (the current executing process).

Though I can start B.exe I cannot close my current process i.e A.exe.

Code I use is:

```
//Start the BT Setup Process
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\TEST\B.exe");
Process.Start(startInfo);

//Terminate the FSA 
Process[] myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
foreach (Process process in myProcess)
{
    process.CloseMainWindow();
    //all the windows messages has to be processed in the msg queue
    //hence call to Application DoEvents forces the MSG
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: by the way i dont want to use Process.Kill() method

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Process.Kill()` method?

Comment: cos it doesnt call my cleanup code

Comment: Why not call your cleanup code manually and then call Kill? As others have mentioned you should look into why Application.Exit() doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 11):

Why do you want to close `A` from `B` while `A` cat start `B` and then close by itself?

```
Process.Start("A.exe");
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); // or Application.Exit(); or anything else
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're falling into this quest of starting a process, and kill your own process after, use `Environment.Exit(0)`, not `Application.Exit()`.

Comment: The application will not exit if there are any active foreground threads; Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); seems more deterministic.

Comment: This is very important... because, there's times where you do not want to kill threads... right? And sometimes you do!

Answer (score 3):

Try [Process.Kill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) instead of  [Process.CloseMainWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx).

Comment: I do not want to use Process.Kill() as it doesnt call my cleanup code

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but in .net 4.0 you can do

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\TEST\B.exe");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;//This should not block your program
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Then Application.Exit or whatever
I tested with a winforms application using the close form method after launching a console app that just blocks on Console.readline();

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to close the current process you should be able to just call [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) rather than looping through and closing processes.

Comment: Using Application.Exit hangs my A.exe application. That is the reason i use Process.CloseMainWindow()

Comment: @srivatsa: If calling `Application.Exit` in your process makes it hang, then I'd say that it might be worth trying to find out why, that might automatically answer your question above as well.